# After using a LineSegmentDetector on an image, how can I retrieve the data, and can I choose how small of a line segment to detect?

Tags: java, image, opencv

I'm trying to design a program that will recognize the rectangle in the image below. After running the Line Segment Detector from OpenCV, I'm left with the second image.

I can clearly see the rectangle, and I want to start filtering out garbage line segments, but I can't seem to find any way to retrieve the data of the line segments created.

It would also be helpful if, with the initial .detect method, I could explicity say "no lines smaller than 20 pixels". Is that possible?

A full working sample of my code is below:

```
public class VinDetector {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        File input = new File("image.jpg");
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);  

        byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Mat sourceImg = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        sourceImg.put(0, 0, data);

        Mat destImage = new Mat(image.getHeight(),image.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceImg, destImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        MatOfFloat4 lines = new MatOfFloat4();
        LineSegmentDetector ls = Imgproc.createLineSegmentDetector();
        ls.detect(destImage, lines);

        System.out.println(ls.compareSegments(new Size(destImage.width(), destImage.height()), lines, lines));


        Mat lineImage = Imgcodecs.imread("image black.jpg");
        ls.drawSegments(lineImage, lines);
        Imgcodecs.imwrite("image TEST.jpg", lineImage);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

[image: Original]
[image: After line segment detector]

Comment: Line segments are returned as a vector of their endpoints. All you need to do is create a function to compute their lengths (Euclidean distance from their endpoints) and filter them by their lengths. Toss the small ones, toss the long ones, and you'll be left with mostly the ones with the length you care about. Then you'll have to filter by proximity---i.e. if they're not near another line, toss them out. See how many lines you have after filtering them.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I've looked through the sparse Java docs for OpenCV and the LineSegmentDetector.detect() function returns void. What function do I get these vectors from? I believe it would be stored in my MatOfFloat4 variable "lines" but I haven't been able to extract the vectors from that data type. 

lines.get(x, y); returns a jumble of letters (a memory address?) but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: I've never used the Java implementation myself. [Here's the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/imgproc/LineSegmentDetector.html) for the Java implementation of the `LineSegmentDetector`. Looking around the web I see people sending the `MatOfFloat4` object to an array with `lines.toArray()` and then indexing I think by bytes? Idk, [see here](http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2015/07/21/opencv-and-processing-19/) for example.